# How can I new field to checkout page on opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have an opencart site. I add new field to shipping method section on checkout. I also add new row  to orders table for this field. But I could not post this fields value to database on confirm order.

I need your helps. 
Thanks...

I added shipper_id to following query in order.php

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($data['invoice_prefix']) . "', shipper_id = '" . (int)$data['shipper_id'] . "', store_id = '" . (int)$data['store_id'] . "', store_name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['store_name']) . "', store_url = '" . $this->db->escape($data['store_url']) . "', customer_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_id'] . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$data['customer_group_id'] . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db->escape($data['fax']) . "', payment_firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_firstname']) . "', payment_lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_lastname']) . "', payment_company = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_company']) . "', payment_company_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_company_id']) . "', payment_tax_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_tax_id']) . "', payment_address_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_address_1']) . "', payment_address_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_address_2']) . "', payment_city = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_city']) . "', payment_postcode = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_postcode']) . "', payment_country = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_country']) . "', payment_country_id = '" . (int)$data['payment_country_id'] . "', payment_zone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_zone']) . "', payment_zone_id = '" . (int)$data['payment_zone_id'] . "', payment_address_format = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_address_format']) . "', payment_method = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_method']) . "', payment_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['payment_code']) . "', shipping_firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_firstname']) . "', shipping_lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_lastname']) . "', shipping_company = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_company']) . "', shipping_address_1 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_address_1']) . "', shipping_address_2 = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_address_2']) . "', shipping_city = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_city']) . "', shipping_postcode = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_postcode']) . "', shipping_country = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_country']) . "', shipping_country_id = '" . (int)$data['shipping_country_id'] . "', shipping_zone = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_zone']) . "', shipping_zone_id = '" . (int)$data['shipping_zone_id'] . "', shipping_address_format = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_address_format']) . "', shipping_method = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_method']) . "', shipping_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['shipping_code']) . "', comment = '" . $this->db->escape($data['comment']) . "', total = '" . (float)$data['total'] . "', affiliate_id = '" . (int)$data['affiliate_id'] . "', commission = '" . (float)$data['commission'] . "', language_id = '" . (int)$data['language_id'] . "', currency_id = '" . (int)$data['currency_id'] . "', currency_code = '" . $this->db->escape($data['currency_code']) . "', currency_value = '" . (float)$data['currency_value'] . "', ip = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ip']) . "', forwarded_ip = '" .  $this->db->escape($data['forwarded_ip']) . "', user_agent = '" . $this->db->escape($data['user_agent']) . "', accept_language = '" . $this->db->escape($data['accept_language']) . "', date_added = NOW(), date_modified = NOW()");
```

I added following code to catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_method.php
 my new field name and id is shipper_id

```
if (isset($this->session->data['shipper_id'])) {
            $this->data['shipper_id'] = $this->session->data['shipper_id'];
        } else {
            $this->data['shipper_id'] = '';
        }
```

On checkout it posts 0 to shipper_id row

Comment: Please add the file name and the query you've updated for inserting those new fields

Comment: I add field to catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/shipping_method.tpl

Comment: Please, provide us with the code You are using for inserting the value. Add the code into Your question.

Comment: And insert query to catalog/model/checkout/order.php

Comment: Update your question with that insert query. Also add the changes you've made in controller file.

Comment: The problem seems like - you've not added the data (shipper_id) to the session variable: `$this->session->data['shipper_id']`. You need to set the session variable in `validate` function in `catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_method.php`.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this. Because I spend about 3 hours, and I could not solve it...

Comment: which line in validate function...

Comment: I added to end of the validate function but did not work

Comment: Sorry I have to finish this job today and I stacked this point...

Comment: Is thre anyone can help me

Comment: Come on.... I've been trying to solve this problem from the morning but still can not post input type=text to db...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare that new variable in confirm.php and check that shipper_id value is getting in module/order.php page.